# Image not printing on window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm not sure why this is happening, or how to fix it.

I'm opening a new window, writing html to that window and then printing the html content from that window with the window.print() method.  Everything shows up in Chrome's default print window except for one image.  This is quite frustrating especially since there are two images being displayed on the page and only one of them gets printed while the other one does not.

What's even more frustrating is that if I just do ctrl+p within that window, it prints both images... I don't understand it.  I don't have any media-print queries or anything that would make it so that the image doesn't print, so I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

The image does load on the page before it gets printed, I made sure of this by setting a timeout to 5 seconds and it still does the same thing.  I would think 5 seconds for an image to load from a local source would be enough.

Here are some snippets of my code.

QuotePDF.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../../StyleSheets/QuotePDF.css';
import ATALogo from '../../../public/Images/ataLogo.png';

export default class QuotePDF extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            AdImage: this.props.AdImage,
            UserEmail: this.props.UserEmail,
            EmailBody: this.props.EmailBody,
            User: this.props.User,
            CustomerInfo: this.props.CustomerInfo,
            CustomerId: this.props.CustomerId,
            FormattedDate: this.props.FormattedDate,
            Quotes: this.props.Quotes,
            singleTotal: "",
            singleAnnualTotal: "",
            doubleTotal: "",
            doubleAnnualTotal: "",
            bannerTotal: "",
            bannerAnnualTotal: "",
        }
    }

    GenerateQuoteNumber(){

        var todaysDate = new Date();
        var rep = this.state.User;
        var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        var month = todaysDate.getMonth();
        var date = todaysDate.getDate();
        var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();
        var monthChar = "";
        var yearChar = "";
        var repInits = "";
        var quoteNumber = "";
        
        if(date < 10){
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        
        rep = rep.split(' ');
        year = year.toString();
        repInits = rep[0][0] + rep[1][0];
        monthChar = chars[month];
        year = year.split('');
        yearChar = chars[year[1]];
        quoteNumber = repInits + "Q" + monthChar + date + yearChar + year[2] + year[3];
 
         return quoteNumber;
     }

    ....

    render(){
        if(this.props.CustomerInfo != 0){
            var customerName = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["Customer First Name"] + " " + this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["Customer Last Name"];
            var businessName = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["Business Name"];
            var customerAddress = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["Street"];
            var customerCity = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["City"];
            var customerState = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["State"];
            var customerZip = this.props.CustomerInfo.extended_info.fields_by_name["Zip"];
        }
        

        return(
            <div id="mainpage" style={
                {width: '95%', maxWidth: '972px', margin: 'auto', fontFamily: 'Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif'}
            }>
                    <div id="innerMainPage" style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                        <div id="leftside" style={{float: 'left', width: '54%', marginLeft: '2%', fontSize: '11px'}}>
                            <div className='ATAImageDiv2' style={{width: '100%', height: '53px', maxWidth: '972px', display: 'block'}}>
                                <img style={{width: '150px', position: 'relative', right: '5%'}} className='ATALogoImage2' name='ATALogo' src={ATALogo} alt="ATALogo"/>
                            </div>

                            <p style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '13px', position: 'relative', right: '3%'}}>SYT Solutions</p>

                        </div>
                        <div id="rightside" style={{textAlign: 'right', width: '45%', float: 'left', fontSize: '11px'}}>
                            <p style={{marginBottom: '7%', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.state.User}</p>
                            <div style={{marginBottom: '7%'}}>
                                <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Address</p>
                                <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Street</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href={`mailto:${this.props.UserEmail}?subject=Quote&body=${this.props.EmailBody}`}><button>Click To Accept</button></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                <div id="quotetitle" style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '14px', borderBottom: '1px solid black', width: '100%', marginBottom: '2.5%'}}>
                    QUOTE
                </div>
            
                <div id="innerMainPage" style={{display: 'block'}}>
                    <div id="leftside2" style={{float: 'left', width: '54%', marginLeft: '2%', fontSize: '11px'}}>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>{businessName}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Attention: {customerName}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>{customerAddress}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>{customerCity}, {customerState} {customerZip}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="rightside" style={{width: '20%', float: 'left', fontSize: '11px', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Quote Number</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Date</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Customer No.</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>Reference</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="innerrightside" style={{textAlign: 'right', fontSize: '11px'}}>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}># {this.GenerateQuoteNumber()}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>{this.props.FormattedDate}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>{this.props.CustomerId}</p>
                        <p style={{margin: '0', padding: '0', marginTop: '4px'}}>PO 27687</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <table id="quotetable" style={{width: '100%', marginTop: '4%', border: '1px solid black', fontSize: '9px'}}>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>StoreID</th>
                            <th style={{width: '10%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Store Name</th>
                            <th style={{width: '25%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Store Address, City</th>
                            <th style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Next Start Date</th>
                            <th style={{width: '10%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Impressions</th>
                            <th style={{width: '4%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Single Ad</th>
                            <th style={{width: '6%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Single Annual</th>
                            <th style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Double Ad</th>
                            <th style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Double Annual</th>
                            <th style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Banner</th>
                            <th style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}>Banner Annual</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table id="innertable" style={{width: '100%', borderBottom: '1px solid black', fontSize: '9px'}}>
                    {this.RenderPriceList(this.props.Quotes)}
                </table>
            
                
                    <table id="quotetableTotals" style={{width: '100%', marginTop: '2%', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '11px'}}>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>TOTAL</td>
                                <td style={{width: '10%', textAlign: 'center'}}></td>
                                <td style={{width: '25%', textAlign: 'center'}}></td>
                                <td style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}></td>
                                <td style={{width: '10%', textAlign: 'center'}}></td>
                                <td style={{width: '4%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.singleTotal}</td>
                                <td style={{width: '6%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.singleAnnualTotal}</td>
                                <td style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.doubleTotal}</td>
                                <td style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.doubleAnnualTotal}</td>
                                <td style={{width: '5%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.bannerTotal}</td>
                                <td style={{width: '7%', textAlign: 'center'}}>${this.state.bannerAnnualTotal}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                
                {this.ResizeImage()}

                <div id="adproof" style={{display: 'block', paddingTop: '5%', width: '50%', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}}>
                    <img id="imgproof" name='ADProof' src={this.props.AdImage} alt="" height="25%" width="100%" scrolling="no"/>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

sorry for all the inline styling, as this seems to be the only way getting it to format right works.

ClientFile.js

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class ClientFile.js extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
... some state stuff
sortedArray: this.props.quotes
}
}

RenderPDF(sortedArray){

       ... some more fun stuff

            return (
                <div id="HiddenQuote">
                    <QuotePDF Quotes={sortedArray} FormattedDate={todaysDate} CustomerId={customerId} AdImage={this.state.AdImage} User={this.state.User} UserEmail={this.state.UserEmail} EmailBody={emailBody} CustomerInfo={this.state.CustomerInfo}></QuotePDF>
                </div>
            );
        }else{
            return (<div></div>);
        }

    }

savePDF(){
        //window.print();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var html = document.getElementById("HiddenQuote").innerHTML;

            var myWindow = window.open("", "", "");
            myWindow.document.write(html);
            myWindow.print();
            //myWindow.close();
        }, 1000);
    }

render(){
return(
<div id="maincontainer">
 ... some interesting stuff
<button onClick={this.SavePDF.bind(this)}>Save PDF</button>
{this.RenderPDF(this.state.sortedArray)}
</div>
)
}

}
```

Here is what it looks like when I use window.print().  The second image is there I just blocked the rest of it for privacy purposes.
[image]

And this is what it looks like if i just ctrl+p on that window.
[image]

The latter shows both images, but I don't understand why both won't show up with the print() method.
If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would appreciate it greatly! Thanks.

Comment: Leaning towards a CSS issue. Your image has right: 5% but what is that relative to? The direct parent? Just a thought.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach are you saying that having right: 5% might be causing it to be off screen?  I did that just for alignment purposes really.

Comment: Inspect the print dialog with the browser and see if your image is where you think it should be? Could rule out CSS positioning being the cause.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I honestly have no idea what it is.  I can put as many img tags with that same image all over the page and none of them display on window.print()

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach I noticed that I only had the width specified on that image, so I added the height attribute to the image and now it shows up on print().  Is there something within the print method that ignores images without both specified?

Comment: No clue. The web is a funny place :)

Comment: I have the same problem; I added the height attribute but still not showing !